# Как получить UniqueID для Android на XE7

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

Как получить идетификационный номер (UniqueID) для устройства для Android на XE7

Мне нужно, что бы у каждого телефона (или планшета) был свой код идентификации. Нашел проект DeviceInfo который дает

1. Название ОS
2. Тип ОС
3. Версия ОС

там есть код

```
procedure TDeviceInfoForm.btnGetDeviceInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  codename: string;
begin
  codename := 'Unknown';
  lbDeviceType.Text := Format('Device Type: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MODEL)]);

  lbOSName.Text := Format('OS Name: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE)]);
  lbOSVersion.Text := Format('OS Version: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE)]);
end;
```

Может у кого есть практика в этом? Из каких полей это можно составить?

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо за ответ, но можно ли получить Google Plus или другое с классом TJBuild как я показал в коде? Мне главное, что бы серийный номер не повторялся и простым методом нельзя было изменить. Мне нужно для защиты программы. Что бы программа не работала в оффлайн копировании другому телефону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покопался в интернете, единого ответа для офф-лайн приложений нету. Везде как сказал @metalurgus нужно идентифицировать пользователя через интернет.

Но решил так

```
implementation
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
uses
  androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  androidapi.JNI.Os;
{$ENDIF}

{$R *.fmx}
{$R *.LgXhdpiPh.fmx ANDROID}


{$IFDEF ANDROID}


procedure TDeviceInfoForm.btnGetDeviceInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('Device Type: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MODEL)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('getRadioVersion: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.getRadioVersion)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('BOARD: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.BOARD)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('BOOTLOADER: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.BOOTLOADER)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('BRAND: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.BRAND)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('CPU_ABI: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.CPU_ABI)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('CPU_ABI2: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.CPU_ABI2)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('DEVICE: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.DEVICE)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('DISPLAY: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.DISPLAY)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('FINGERPRINT: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.FINGERPRINT)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('HARDWARE: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.HARDWARE)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('HOST: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.HOST)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('ID: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.ID)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('MANUFACTURER: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MANUFACTURER)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('MODEL: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.MODEL)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('PRODUCT: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.PRODUCT)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('RADIO: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.RADIO)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('SERIAL: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.SERIAL)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('TAGS: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.TAGS)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('TIME: %s', [IntToStr(TJBuild.JavaClass.TIME)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('&TYPE: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.&TYPE)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('UNKNOWN: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.UNKNOWN)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('USER: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild.JavaClass.USER)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('CODENAME: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.CODENAME)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('INCREMENTAL: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.INCREMENTAL)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('RELEASE: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.RELEASE)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('SDK: %s', [JStringToString(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK)]));
ListBox2.Items.Add(Format('SDK_INT: %s', [IntToStr(TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT)]));

end;
{$ENDIF}
```

тут есть поля как SERIAL, DISPLAY, MODEL, RELEASE.

Как получить `IMEI` телефона

```
uses
  androidapi.JNI.Telephony,
  androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  androidapi.JNIBridge,
  androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

...

var 
  obj: JObject;
  tm: JTelephonyManager;
  identifier: String;

begin
  obj := SharedActivityContext.getSystemService
    (TJContext.JavaClass.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  if obj <> nil then
  begin
    tm := TJTelephonyManager.Wrap((obj as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if tm <> nil then
      identifier := JStringToString(tm.getDeviceId);
  end;
  ListBox2.Items.Add('identifier 1: '+identifier);

  if identifier = '' then
    identifier := JStringToString(TJSettings_Secure.JavaClass.getString
      (SharedActivity.getContentResolver,
      TJSettings_Secure.JavaClass.ANDROID_ID));

        ListBox2.Items.Add('identifier 2: '+identifier);
end;
```

решил пользоватся ими и создать ключ. потом регистрировать через SMS у кого нету интернета.

код взял **[отюда](http://delphifmandroid.blogspot.com/2014/01/device-information.html)** для IMEI **[отсюда](http://www.fmxexpress.com/read-the-imei-device-id-with-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android/)**

Спасибо, @kami, за совет. коды получил, но по политику этого сайта код должен быть в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Для `Android` нет абсолютно надежного способа идентифицировать устройство. Есть один штатный метод, но он возвращает другой `ID` после перепрошивки, его можно подделать при помощи `ROOT`, на некоторых устройствах он и вовсе не работает. Можете попробовать привязываться к `ID` какого-то оборудования, например к `MAC-адрессу` `WIFI` или `BLUETOOTH`, но я не могу гарантировать, что они не меняются. Как показывает практика, наиболее надежным способом является идентификация именно пользователя, а не устройства. Пример - авторизация через `Google Plus`, `VK`, `Facebook` и т. д.

Comment: можете показать пример кода, для получения МАС адреса или другого серийного номера любого оборудования. Мне нужно именно в Delphi, в java у меня все получается.

Comment: @Saidolim С разрешения автора кода оставлю здесь ссылку: http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/1762-deviceinfo-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B5/ Разрешения на копирование части кода не получал, поэтому как ответ не могу оформить. Рекомендую пересмотреть политику привязки, как советует metalurgus. Учитывайте фактор китайфонов - там все идентификаторы могут быть левыми (если не вообще забиты нулями).